# I need JSON Extractor to only work when the condition is satisfied

Tags: json, jmeter, performance-testing

In JMeter I need JSON Extractor to only extract, if a condition is satisfied, since if it tries to extract data that does not exist, it will not let the sampler that its attached to go.
[In the screenshot you can see ticketId <<< JSON, i need it to not start extracting if totalRecords = 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gUck.png)

I hope there is a tool suitable for that in JMeter

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as of [JMeter 5.6.3](https://lists.apache.org/list?user@jmeter.apache.org:2024-1) you cannot apply PreProcessors conditionally. There is `Default Values` section where you can provide some placeholder value in case if extraction fails:

[image]

It will be stored into a JMeter Variable and then the variable can be used later on for example in [If Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#If_Controller)

---

Alternatively you can use [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) instead of JSON Extractor,

[Groovy has built-in JSON support](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html) and it's also possible to use the same [JsonPath library](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) which is used in the JSON Extractor:

Something like:

```
if (vars.get('recordsTotal') != '0') {
    vars.putObject('your-variable-name-here', com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(prev.getResponseDataAsString(), 'your-jsonpath-expression-here'))
}
```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)